# Folder not being copied to Output directory

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, npm, .net-core, msbuild

I have the following on an ASP.NET Core 3.1 csproj file:

```
  <ItemGroup> 
    <Content Include="webroot\**"> 
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory> 
    </Content> 
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Approot" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforePublish">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="approot" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="approot" Command="npm run build --prod" />
  </Target>
```

I am building a Client application in `approot` folder and saving the result to webroot folder.

I need the webfoot folder to be copied to the Output directory ...

**Problem**

When I build it files are placed on webfoot folder but it is not copied to the Output.

So I need to rebuild it again so that webroot folder is copied to the Output ...

It seems that the 2 npm commands are being ran after the Build but I am using BeforeBuild.

Answer (score 17):

Try this

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="wwwroot\**">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Comment: That gives the error: "The source file "wwwroot/" is actually a directory.  The "Copy" task does not support copying directories.

Comment: Just used this on a net core 3.1 project and it worked like a champ.

Comment: I found that this can SOMETIMES fail if the directory has NO FILES, and doesn't copy the directory. 

You can add a blank file, and add indicate this file should be copied via Visual Studio properties dialog (CopyToOutputDirectory = Always).

Answer (score 0):

I try to create blank .net core 3.1 project and when I click on publish I get the publish folder in `bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1`

[image]

You can view my full csproj file [here](https://pastebin.com/ub1ZY3hS)

Comment: It is not the publish folder I don't get ... It's the `webroot` folder

Answer (score 0):

You can "force"  the copy using the sample below. It works for me on a React client app.

```
<Target Name="Approot" BeforeTargets="BeforeBuild;BeforePublish">
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="approot" Command="npm install" />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="approot" Command="npm run build --prod" />

    <!-- Include the newly-built files in the publish output -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <DistFiles Include="approot\build\**" />
      <ResolvedFileToPublish Include="@(DistFiles->'%(FullPath)')" Exclude="@(ResolvedFileToPublish)">
        <RelativePath>%(DistFiles.Identity)</RelativePath>
        <CopyToPublishDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToPublishDirectory>
      </ResolvedFileToPublish>
    </ItemGroup>
</Target>
```

Comment: Does this copy to wwwroot of the published directory?